# Question about if referer stays the same if you edit URL in dev tools

Tags: http

If someone is on my website, and they use dev tools to edit a button on my website and change the URL to a different URL, then they click that button, do the HTTP headers and referer still look exactly the same as if the website owner put it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on *any* header. Everything can be modified. Distrust everything coming from a HTTP client.